# Using named result params partially to set defaults

Tags: go

Let's say I have a function with 3 return values. I set the values of 2 of them, and want to leave the 3rd one to default if I do not set it. Something like this -

```
func call(a int) (int, int, r3 string){

  //        return a, a+1, "no error" // stmt 1
  //        return a, a+1             // stmt 2
  //        return                    // stmt 3
}
```

Running with stmt 2 or stmt 3 uncommented, I get below error -

```
duplicate argument int
int is shadowed during return
```

How is int shadowed here? The return list does not have named int params.

Running with stmt 1 uncommented, I get below error -

```
duplicate argument int
cannot use a (type int) as type string in return argument
cannot use a + 1 (type int) as type string in return argument
```

Can someone explain origin of these errors ?

Is it not possible to have partial list of named result params (or even returning variables when using named result params) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)
>
> Within a list of parameters or results, the names (IdentifierList)
>   must either all be present or all be absent. If present, each name
>   stands for one item (parameter or result) of the specified type and
>   all non-blank names in the signature must be unique. If absent, each
>   type stands for one item of that type.

---

```
package main

// duplicate argument int
func call1(a int) (int, int, r3 string) {
    // int is shadowed during return
    return
}

// duplicate argument int
func call2(a int) (int string, int string, r3 string) {
    // int is shadowed during return
    return
}

// duplicate argument int
func call3(a bool) (int, int, r3 string) {
    // int is shadowed during return
    return
}

func call4(a int) (int, r2, r3 string) {
    return
}

func call5(a int) (r1, r2, r3 string) {
    return
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/PUhY7Y0H9f

Output:

```
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:4:33: duplicate argument int
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:6:2: int is shadowed during return
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:10:47: duplicate argument int
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:12:2: int is shadowed during return
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:16:34: duplicate argument int
tmp/sandbox842451638/main.go:18:2: int is shadowed during return
```

---

`call1` is shorthand for `call2`. As you can see, you have duplicate return argument names `int`: "all non-blank names in the signature must be unique." The first return argument name `int` is shadowed by the second return argument name `int`.

---

If you want anonymous return arguments, you can use the blank identifier.

```
package main

// duplicate argument int
func callA(a int) (int, int, r3 string) {
    // int is shadowed during return
    return
}

func callB(a int) (_ int, _ int, r3 string) {
    return
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CS1x9mmIh6

Comment: Doesn't shadowing occur for same name variables, if redeclared? I changed (a int) to (a bool) and still got the same shadowing error on empty return.

Comment: @peterSO I believe this is not correct: "The call argument, `(a int)`, type `int` is shadowed by the return argument names `int`." Change it to `(a float64)` and you get the same error, change one return int to float64 and you lose the error. What the error means is that the first return variable named `int` is shadowed by the second return variable named `int`. https://play.golang.org/p/YkuPSxkC-4.